# Field 'doors' expected a number but got ''

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

#### Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

The above exception (invalid literal for int() with base 10: '') was the direct cause of the following exception:
  File "/home/andres/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/andres/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "./wallacar_app/views.py", line 124, in getDoors
    doors = Coche.objects.exclude(doors__isnull=True).exclude(doors__exact='').order_by('doors').values_list('doors').distinct()
  File "/home/andres/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 949, in exclude
    return self._filter_or_exclude(True, args, kwargs)
  File "/home/andres/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 961, in _filter_or_exclude
    clone._filter_or_exclude_inplace(negate, args, kwargs)
  File "/home/andres/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 966, in _filter_or_exclude_inplace
    self._query.add_q(~Q(*args, **kwargs))
  File "/home/andres/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1396, in add_q
    clause, _ = self._add_q(q_object, self.used_aliases)
  File "/home/andres/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1418, in _add_q
    split_subq=split_subq, check_filterable=check_filterable,
  File "/home/andres/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1350, in build_filter
    condition = self.build_lookup(lookups, col, value)
  File "/home/andres/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1196, in build_lookup
    lookup = lookup_class(lhs, rhs)
  File "/home/andres/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/lookups.py", line 25, in __init__
    self.rhs = self.get_prep_lookup()
  File "/home/andres/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_lookups.py", line 117, in get_prep_lookup
    self.rhs = target_field.get_prep_value(self.rhs)
  File "/home/andres/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 1827, in get_prep_value
    ) from e

Exception Type: ValueError at /wallacar_app/ajax/doors/
Exception Value: Field 'doors' expected a number but got ''.
```

#### models.py

```
class Coche(models.Model):
    doors = models.ForeignKey('CocheDoors', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class CocheDoors(models.Model):
    doors = models.IntegerField(verbose_name="Puertas", primary_key=True, validators=[RegexValidator(regex='^[0-9]{1}$',message="Las puertas solo pueden tener una cifra")])
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.doors)
```

#### views.py

```
def getDoors(request):
    if request.method == "GET" and request.is_ajax():
        doors = Coche.objects.exclude(doors__isnull=True).exclude(doors__exact='').order_by('doors').values_list('doors').distinct()
        doors = [i[0] for i in list(doors)]
        data = {'doors':doors}
        return JsonResponse(data,status=200)
```

USED: Django 3.1.7, Python 3.6.9, Ajax, Postgresql and Django Rest Framework. Im trying to doing dinamics dropdown filters. This is not the full code of my application. I think the error are here. 
 Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your field `doors` is defined as `IntegerField` with `null=False` and `blank=False` (by default).

Therefore, the following line of your code is the problem (breaks added for readability):

```
doors = Coche.objects \
    .exclude(doors__isnull=True) \
    .exclude(doors__exact='') \
    .order_by('doors') \
    .values_list('doors').distinct()
```

`.exclude(doors__exact='')` throws the error because an `IntegerField` must not contain a string but you are checking whether it equals the empty string `''`. This is not allowed.

`.exclude(doors__isnull=True)` is not necessary as long as you do not set `null=True` in the `doors` field definition of your model.